# How to add box shadow to a grid container?

Tags: css, css-grid, shadow

This is my first post here and I am completely new to this field. I am unable to add box-shadow to my grid container. It has 3 grid-items in it and I want to add a shadow to my entire container.

Here is my container CSS code:

```
.container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: minmax(auto,350px) minmax(auto,350px);
    grid-template-rows: auto auto;
    height: 100vh;
    align-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

So, I tried directly applying box-shadow in my container that didn't work.

Then I tried applying the shadow to all the grid-items I have. But it overlaps with another item so it doesn't look good.

Also, I found the CSS Pseudo-elements and saw some solution with that but I didn't understand the procedure there.

**Update: The problem is fixed. There was no parent for my grid-container. So I used the body as my grid-container's parent and that worked.**

```
body {
    background-color: hsl(204, 43%, 93%);
    display: grid;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100vh;
}

.container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: minmax(auto,350px) minmax(auto,350px);
    grid-template-rows: auto auto;
    box-shadow: 0 10px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

Comment: How did you apply the box-shaddow? If you add a border instead of a box shaddow, does it display properly?

Comment: @TimNikischin You are the lifesaver man. I added the border and figured out what was happening. I edited my body as the parent of my main container and it worked fine. Thank you so much.

Comment: You are very welcome! Maybe consider upvoting my comment. Thank you!

Comment: @TimNikischin Yeah sure am trying to do that but I can't find the upvoting icons. The comment is shown as a tiny line bottom of my post without any upvoting system or anything. Am completely new to stack overflow. So am figuring it out. I will give you an upvote soon. Oh, I think I will need 15 reputation points to upvote.

Comment: No worries, thank you for your feedback, appreciate it!